# Permisos de acceso a Cámara y Galería fluido - Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-asynctask, android-permissions

Tengo este procedimiento que se encarga de solicitar al cliente su consentimiento para acceder a la galeria, a la camara y poder subir una foto a la nube la primera vez que el cliente presiona el boton de `Galeria` o `Camara`.

El problema es que los pide 1 cada vez que se presiona el botón de la galería hasta completarlos todos.

Ejemplo:

Click 1: Permiso para cámara.

Click 2: Permiso para guardar imagen.

Click 3: Permiso para ver la galeria. Etc..

**Y lo que necesito es que pida todos los permisos uno a uno pero con solo el 1er click.** Hay alguna forma de decirle que espere la respuesta para continuar el procedimiento utilizando el `await`?

```
public async Task SolicitarPermisosdeCamarayGaleria()
        {
            try
            {
                var permissionStatus = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Camera>();

                if (permissionStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    permissionStatus = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Camera>();
                }

                var permissionStatus2 = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Media>();
                if (permissionStatus2 != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    permissionStatus2 = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Media>();
                }

                var permissionStatus3 = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Photos>();
                if (permissionStatus3 != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    permissionStatus3 = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Photos>();
                }

                var permissionStatus4 = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
                if (permissionStatus4 != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    permissionStatus4 = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
                }

                var permissionStatus5 = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
                if (permissionStatus5 != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    permissionStatus5 = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
                }

                //validacion
                if (permissionStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted && permissionStatus2 != PermissionStatus.Granted && permissionStatus3 != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    ShowToast("Necesita habilitar los permisos para poder agregar una imagen a su publicacion", false);                   
                }
                    
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                string LineErrorNumber = Ex.StackTrace.Substring(Ex.StackTrace.Length - 7, 7) + "Error: " + Ex.Message;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Has un Array con los permisos y luego lo ejecutas en el botón

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo necesitamos lo que desencadena el pedir los permisos (en este caso un ImageView que nos sirve de botón llamado Icono).

```
Icono = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ImgPermisos);
Icono.Click += async delegate
            {                    
                RequestPermissions(PermisosParaPublicarImagenes, PermisosHabilitados);                    
            };

const int PermisosHabilitados = 0;
```

Aquí tenemos el arreglo de los permisos a solicitar:

```
        readonly string[] PermisosParaPublicarImagenes = 
            {
            Android.Manifest.Permission.Camera,
            Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage,
            Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage
        };
```

Y este es el resultado de la actividad de permisos (si el cliente acepto o no los permisos).
Aca puedes desencadenar si llamas a la galería, a la cámara o a lo que quieras.

```
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            if (grantResults[0] == 0 && grantResults[1] == 0 && grantResults[2] == 0)
            {
                if (CamaraoGaleria==1)
                {
                    TakePhoto();
                }
                else if (CamaraoGaleria == 2)
                {
                    SelectPhoto();
                }

            }
        }
```